# xCode 9 ios 11 : Data's pointer inside struct losing

Tags: objective-c, struct, ios11, xcode9

In my application, I have a `struct` and it contains all of my data. It works well with previous version of Xcode. But when I build it with Xcode 9, beta 5 to iOS 11 device, some data inside is lost. 
That happens, when I pass the `struct` object as parameter by function to another activity.

My struct looks like below:

```
typedef struct {
    NSString *title;
    MainController *mainController;
    //....
    //....
    //more than 200 objects
} mystruct;
```

After data loss, when I try to access it Xcode shows [EXC_BAD_ACCESS] and application crashes.
Is there any size limit to structures in Xcode 9?

**UPDATE 1:** add creating and passing source

```
//declare struct
mystruct m;
memset(&m,0,sizeof(mystruct));
// setting data for struct
....
...
...
// passing param
[anotherObj showData:&m];
```

Method read value of another object :

```
- (void)showData:(mystruct *)ms
{
    // get data of struct
    [self showText : ms->title];
}
```

**NOTE:** It only happens on xCode 9 and iOS 11

- xCode 9 + iOS 11 -> Error
- xCode 9 + iOS 10 -> OK
- xCode 8 + iOS 11 ->OK
- xCode 8 + iOS 10 -> OK
- xCode 7 + iOS 11 -> OK
- xCode 7 + iOS 10 ->OK

Comment: Please add the code for creating the structure object and passing it. Moreover the code of the function taking the parameter.

Comment: i have added creating and passing source code .

Comment: Didn't you get warnings for having a struct with references? This is pure Objective-C, not Objective-C++? Do you use ARC?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion . I don't use ARC .

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by myself . The reason is because when build app on xCode 9 . It forces my app build with 64-bit compiler .

There was a warning from Apple doc about [Be Careful When Aligning 64-Bit Integer types] . But i didn't notice it .
Link : [Apple doc about aligning bit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013501-CH3-SW20)

Then, i just add pragma like they teach and it worked well .

```
#pragma pack(4)
struct bar {
    int32_t foo0;
    int32_t foo1;
    int32_t foo2;
    int64_t bar;
};
#pragma options align=reset
```

Another way , we can reorganize the elements with the largest alignment values first and the smallest elements last to avoid padding bit .

@Amin Negm-Awad : Thanks for your help